# Check by definition if the limit of $a_n = (-1)^n + 1/n$ exists.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Check by definition if the limit of $a_n = (-1)^n + 1/n$ exists.

I have attempted to solve this problem but I am not sure if my reasoning is sound therefore I'd be glad if you could give me some hints. 
First of all, recall the definition: The limit of a sequence, $g$, exists if 
$$(\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists N)(\forall n>N)(|a_n-g|<\epsilon)$$
Now, let's consider two subsequence of the sequence: $a_{2k}, a_{2k-1}, k\in \mathbb N$ 
1. Let's prove that $1$ is the limit of $a_{2k}$: 
$$|1+ \frac{1}{2k}-1|<\epsilon$$
$$2k >\frac{1}{\epsilon}$$
And so let's say that $N_{2k} = [\frac{1}{\epsilon}]+1$ 
2. Let's prove that $-1$ is the limit of $a_{2k+1}$
$$|-1+ \frac{1}{2k+1}+1|< \epsilon $$
$$2k+1 >\frac{1}{\epsilon} $$
Once again let $N_{2k+1} = [\frac{1}{\epsilon}]+1$ 
Now, let's take some $M >N_{2k} \land M>N_{2k+1}$. Let $\epsilon = 1$
Then
$$0 < a_n < 2 \land -2<a_n<0 $$ 
Which is a contradiction.

Comment: In fact, the limit does not exists.

Comment: This is what my reasoning boils down to, isn't it?

Comment: Your argument is right. The statement of the problem is false.

Answer (score 1):

Much shorter:

For $n\ge 1$,
$$|a_{n+1}-a_n|=\left|(-1)^{n+1}+\frac1{n+1}-(-1)^n-\frac1n\right|=\left|2(-1)^n-\frac1{n(n+1)}\right|\ge\frac32$$
Then $a_n$ is not a Cauchy sequence.

EDIT: If you can't even use the fact that every convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence, you can still use the previous bound in the following way:

If $\{a_n\}$ has a limit $L$, then there is some $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $|a_n-L|<1/2$ for every $n\ge n_0$. But then, for every $n\ge n_0$, $1>|a_n-L|+|L-a_{n+1}|\ge|a_{n+1}-a_n|\ge \frac32$. Contradiction.

Comment: But this is not the formal definition of a limit, is it?

Comment: Every convergent sequence must be a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 0):

We need to show that: $\exists \epsilon > 0 : \forall N : \exists n,m > N : |a_{n} - a_{m}| \ge \epsilon.$
Consider $m = n + 1$ and let $\epsilon = 1$.

Comment: Actually that's not a definition , but it's a Cauchy-criteria.

Comment: I haven't thought about this way to solve this, but what about my solution - is it flawed?

Comment: @Aemilius actually look's right. Because since $M$ all members lies in $\epsilon$-area.